# Правильно ли сказать "мариновать шашлык"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правильно ли сказать "мариновать шашлык"? Мы ведь варим суп, хотя супа в кастрюле ещё нет?

Comment: Неверная аналогия. Когда варят суп, то получается суп, а когда "маринуют шашлык", то получается не шашлык, а маринованное мясо. А уже из него можно приготовить шашлык. Или не шашлык.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: **мариновать мясо для шашлыка.**

Мариновать шашлык ― разговорное выражение, в его основе лежит метонимия  (перенос значения по смежности): мясо для шашлыка ― шашлык.

Comment: Чисто по-буквоедски шашлык тоже можно мариновать. Снять с шампура и в маринад! :)

Answer (score 1):

Мне слух не режет. Конечно "мариновать мясо для шашлыка" безупречно во всех отношениях, хотя и длинновато, но вопрос-то не в этом, а в том, правильна ли конструкция "мариновать шашлык".

Я понял вашу мысль, вопрос в том когда шашлык становится шашлыком, на какой стадии. На мой вкус - в тот самый момент, когда мясо разделано под шашлык.
Никого ведь не смущает, что на этикетках и ценниках полуфабрикатов стоит "котлеты","эскалоп" или там "пельмени". И это не метонимия, это общее понимание.

Согласен, в тексте, претендующем на рецептурную точность, я бы не стал использовать, но в обычном нейтральном (не просто разговорном) - почему нет?!